# Qt 5.2 QImage rgbSwapped() and scaled() runs ridiculously slow

Tags: c++, qt

These two operations take more than 100ms in a Ivy Bridge i3 based mobile device.
The intresting thing is, that the same operation runs much faster (at least 5 times) if I compile with Qt 4.8.

The only difference is, that I use this constructor to make the QImage under Qt 5.2:

[`QImage::QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, Format format )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#QImage-4)

and this one under Qt 4.8 (from Qt3 support):

[`QImage ( uchar * data, int width, int height, int depth, const QRgb * colortable, int numColors, Endian bitOrder )`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage-qt3.html#QImage-14)

The data is in `QImage::Format_RGB888` format, 1080p resolution, 720p->1080p at upscale. I use ubuntu 13.10 64bit.

Comment: Have you tried asking here: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewforum/10/  ?

Comment: Do you have a debug version of Qt 5.2 (and a non-debug version of Qt 4.8)? Usually, debug builds are much slower but useful for in-depth debugging during development, and not intended for productive use in the deployment environment for such performance reasons. If you compiled Qt 5.2 yourself, you probably have a debug build.

Comment: Compiled with debug info both time.

Comment: @Eric: it is totally fine to ask here. We have a "qt" tag for a reason...

Comment: No argument there!  Just thought I'd mention the Qt site in case there was no answer here. I haven't encountered that many in-depth Qt answers here (I may just not have seen them), but have there.  That's the only I reason I mentioned it.